# How to align button along with update panel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css, updatepanel

How do I ensure that both the buttons, saveBtn and cancelBtn are displayed next to each other in the following HTML?

I tried using float, but all it ensures is placing the button cancelBtn next to the label in this structure.

```
<div >
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updt" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <label>A</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="aTxt" runat="server"/>
                    <User Control A>
                    <asp:Button ID="saveBtn" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="Save_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                   <asp:Button ID="cancelBtn" Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="Cancel_Click" />
    </div>
```

Please note that I have some UI specific processing logic for which button cancel can't be moved inside the update panel.

Comment: You can't move the save logic outside of the updatepanel and test which view the panel's in an save accordingly? Just shy of using absolute positioning, not sure how you would get them to align.

Comment: Brad, Nopes. I have some UI specific logic which necessitates that I have the save within the panel and there is a jquery/javascript logic for the cancel which does not fire everytime if I place them within the update panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `RenderMode="Inline"` for the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Matthew, would you be able to tell me on how rendering the update panel contents as span help to align 2 buttons - one within an update panel and one outside of it?